In Sharepoint, same Community Site type of site but it return different ids of groups(owner, member, visitor)
I get a problem is I want to get id of each type of user in group(owner, member, visitor) in the Community Portal site like this
Return id of each user in group
but when i return another site (still Community Portal type of site), return ids are different
Return different ids
I know that different types of SharePoint sites (team sites, communication sites, etc.) have different IDs. However, shouldn't objects within the same site have the same ID? Any help understanding why this isn't happening would be appreciated.

It is a normal behavior in the SharePoint.
I have observed the same behavior in my SharePoint. Group IDs for default site groups are different for different sites.

In my case, it is different group ids for same sites groups (community portal). It generates different id in odd number and even number
